# Facebook-share: automatic image detection with og:image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-sharer

I would like to know how I detect a image from a webpage.
I want a code that if I want to share something on facebook the image from the page where I am at that time, automatically detect.

example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.geturl.thedoctorofhouse.com/audi_a3_2.jpg" />
```

What should I do with the og:image content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct - content should contain the url to the image that you want used.

You can check how the page metadata is interpreted by using the [linter tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) provided by Facebook

Comment: No i want to get a random image from the page where i am...? The image http://www.geturl.thedoctorofhouse.com/audi_a3_2.jpg is not the image that i wanted to have.

Comment: So this is not a programming question at all? Chose another image, if Facebook offers more than one – or chose to display the link without any image. That’s about it, when it comes to sharing content that is not yours on Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe I want to select the image(s) that is on the webpage, maybe with a $_GET variabe? I'm not very good with php.

Comment: @CBroe something like this:<code> $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url; </code>